# gdata spreadsheet library for python not working anymore?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gdata

I was trying to run a query for data in one of my google docs, and it's worked for several months. Starting yesterday or the day before, I noticed that my script no longer works. Has Google updated their api for spreadsheets? Has anybody found a workaround?

My error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build_packer_image.py", line 311, in <module>
    for index, entry in enumerate(client.GetWorksheetsFeed(doc_key).entry):
  File "/build/toolchain/mac-10.5-32/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/spreadsheet/service.py", line 129, in GetWorksheetsFeed
    converter=gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsWorksheetsFeedFromString)
  File "/build/toolchain/mac-10.5-32/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/service.py", line 1074, in Get
    return converter(result_body)
  File "/build/toolchain/mac-10.5-32/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/spreadsheet/__init__.py", line 411, in SpreadsheetsWorksheetsFeedFromString
    xml_string)
  File "/build/toolchain/mac-10.5-32/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/__init__.py", line 93, in optional_warn_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/build/toolchain/mac-10.5-32/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/__init__.py", line 127, in CreateClassFromXMLString
    tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xml_string.replace('doctype','DOCTYPE'))
  File "<string>", line 125, in XML
cElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am using:

- Python 2.7.5
- gdata 2.0.18

I am just using an document key and no oauth in my code, if that makes a difference (I am passing in the username and password to the ClientLogin method)

Comment: Have the same problem since May 27, 2015. gdata 2.0.17

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually here is the answer to the problem:

> The use of client login (using username/password instead of oauth2) is
>   likely the cause of the error. That protocol was deprecated 3+ years
>   ago and was just shutdown. If you capture the HTTP response (which
>   appears to have some HTML content), that might confirm if it is
>   related to the shutdown. Migrating to OAuth 2 would get your apps
>   working again.

After sending xml for update in spreadsheet google respond with a login page.
It means the authentication is not working for gdata now

https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3851#c2